# Error While Executing my Stored Procedure in Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to `INSERT` my data into two tables `Services` and `Service-line`

Explaining my stored procedure:

- It checks for existing ID in the Form
- If not found it creates a new record in the `Services` table the info in the Form, then gets the ID using `scope_identity` and uses the `ID` for the `Service-Line` table.

  Also the ID is returned to the Form and stays tre.
- Later while inserting second record in `Service-Line`, the stored procedure checks for existing `ID`; if found, this time, it takes the `ID` from the Form and uses it in the `Service-Line`

This Is my stored procedure

please bear with me, as I am working in this code and testing, a lot of line are commented out

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertServiceServiceLine] (
   --Services Entry

   --FOR IF CONDITION ---CHECK THE DEFAULT VALUE IN THE FORM on SID
   @ExistingSID int,

   --SEELCT PARAMETES DEF VALUES
   @ComboBoxSelectedBike varchar(100),

   -- INPUT PARAMETERES FOR NEW RECORD
   @CID int,
   @Status bit = 1,
   @CurrentMeter int,
   @Labor decimal(20,0),
   @GrandTotal decimal(20,0) = ISNULL,
   --@NextService datetime,

   --Service Line
   @Spare nvarchar(500),
   @Quantity int,
   @Uprice decimal(20,2),
   @Subtotal decimal(20,2)
)
AS
BEGIN

IF (@ExistingSID <= 0)

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @BikeID int

SELECT @BikeID = (SELECT BikeID FROM TblBikeNames WHERE BikeName = @ComboBoxSelectedBike)

INSERT INTO [AutoDB_Sample].[dbo].[TblServices]
(CID,BikeID,Status,CurrentMeter,Labor,DateOfService)

VALUES
(@CID,@BikeID,@Status,@CurrentMeter,@Labor,GETDATE())

DECLARE @SID int

SET @SID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [AutoDB_Sample].[dbo].[TblServiceLine]
(SID,Spare,Quantity,Uprice,Subtotal,DateCreated)

VALUES
(@SID,@Spare,@Quantity,@Uprice,@Subtotal,GETDATE())


RETURN @SID

END

ELSE

BEGIN

INSERT INTO [AutoDB_Sample].[dbo].[TblServiceLine]
(SID,Spare,Quantity,Uprice,Subtotal,DateCreated)

VALUES
(@ExistingSID,@Spare,@Quantity,@Uprice,@Subtotal,GETDATE())

END

END
```

It gives me an error when I use this stored procedure in a C# Windows Forms

> Procedure or Function has too many Arguments

Here's a screenshot of the error

[image: THIS IS THE EXACT ERROR]

I thought that Putting my login in SP would be great and improve the performance of my application. But now am stuck.

This is my C# Code

---

```
public void AddItemIntoServices_ServiceLine()
        {

            ConnectionStringSettings consetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AutoDB"];

            String ConnectionString = consetting.ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                con.Open(); // open the connection

                // Specify the name of the Stored Procedure you will call

                String SP_Name = "InsertServiceServiceLine";

                // Create the SQL Command object and specify that this is a SP.

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_Name, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Specify values for the input parameters of our Stored Procedure
                // Parameters MUST be named the same as the parameters defined in the Stored Procedure. 


                //~~ If Condition Parameter ****************************************************************************~~//

                int exitstingSID;
                if (int.TryParse(LblSID_Data.Text, out exitstingSID)) ;

                SqlParameter ExistingSID = new SqlParameter("@ExistingSID", exitstingSID);
                ExistingSID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ExistingSID.DbType = DbType.Int16;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ExistingSID);

                //Parameter to select Bike ID from Selected Bike Name

                SqlParameter ParamBikeID = new SqlParameter("@ComboBoxSelectedBike",                       ComboBx_BikeNames.Text);
                ParamBikeID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ParamBikeID.DbType = DbType.String;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamBikeID);

                //~~ Customer Info ************************************************************************************~~//

                //CID Convertion
                int P_CID;
                if (int.TryParse(LblCID_Data.Text, out P_CID)) ;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", P_CID);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname", this.TxtBx_CustomerName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vnum", this.TxtBx_VehicleNumber.Text);

                //~~ Service Info ************************************************************************************~~//

                //Labor Convertion
                int Laborint;
                if (int.TryParse(TxtBxLabor.Text, out Laborint)) ;
                SqlParameter ParamLabor = new SqlParameter("@Labor", Laborint);

                ParamLabor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ParamLabor.DbType = DbType.Int16;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamLabor);

               //CurrentMeterConversion

                int currentMeterint;
                if (int.TryParse(TxtBx_CurrentMeter.Text, out currentMeterint)) ;

                SqlParameter ParamCurrentMeter = new SqlParameter("@CurrentMeter", currentMeterint);
                ParamCurrentMeter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ParamCurrentMeter.DbType = DbType.Int16;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamCurrentMeter);


                //Return Value
                SqlParameter ParamReturn = new SqlParameter("@SID", SqlDbType.Int);
                ParamReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                ParamReturn.DbType = DbType.Int16;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamReturn);


                //~~ Service Info ************************************************************************************~~//

                //Converstions
                Decimal UP, ST;
                if (Decimal.TryParse(TxtBx_UnitPrice.Text, out UP)) ;
                if (Decimal.TryParse(TxtBxTotal.Text, out ST)) ;

                //SpareName
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Spare", ComboBx_SparesName.Text);

                //Quantity
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", NumericBx_Quantity.Value);

                //Unit Price
                SqlParameter ParamUp = new SqlParameter("@Uprice", UP);
                ParamUp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ParamUp.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamUp);

                //Total
                SqlParameter ParamTot = new SqlParameter("Subtotal", ST);
                ParamTot.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ParamTot.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamTot);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                String _returnedSID = cmd.Parameters["@SID"].Value.ToString();
                LblSID_Data.Text = _returnedSID;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                clear();
                ToolStripLable_Status.Text = "New Service Record Created";
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think that the problem is in the C# code that calls this sp. Please add that code to your question.

Comment: Message is clear, providing more parameters to SP. Check your parameter where the code calling that SP.

Comment: @Steve . . . I have added the C# code.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo . . SP works juzz fine in SSMS, i juz have this error when i execute it frm C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of parameters passed through the command collection should match exactly what the stored procedure expects by name, type and direction.

Your list of parameters included in the command collection doesn't match with the parameters required by the stored procedure and thus you get the error.

At first sight I could say:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cname", this.TxtBx_CustomerName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vnum", this.TxtBx_VehicleNumber.Text);
SqlParameter ParamReturn = new SqlParameter("@SID", SqlDbType.Int);
```

are parameters added to the command collection but are not present in the stored procedure list of parameters.

On the contrary we have the parameters `@status bit` and  `@GrandTotal decimal(20,0) = ISNULL,` required by the stored procedure but not present in the list. (By The way, the default syntax for a NULL parameter is  `@GrandTotal decimal(20,0) = NULL`

Finally the stored procedure names a parameter `@Quantity` but you add a parameter named `@Qty`.

Now there is also the problem of the parameter types that should match otherwise you risk an automatic conversion at best or a error message stating about type mismatches.

You have numerous parameter of type int but you pass parameters of type Int16 while the correct type is Int32. And there is also a more clear error in the type of the parameter `@Labor` that is expected to be a decimal by the sp but you add it as an integer (16)

Comment: Yes, steve, I corrected it and my code is working fine as expected, and I will change the Null Parameter as you said.

Thankzz

Answer (score 1):

You have 12 parameters in the stored procedure definition (if I counted correctly), however, your code may have more or less than that.  There is either one too many parameters defined within the code, or the stored procedure expects a 13th parameter.  I think the error mentions the former, but I sometimes get them confused.

Anyway that error is always due to a mismatch in the number of parameters, and make sure the direction (input/output) is setup correctly, and everything is typed OK.

Comment: Yes, Brian, Silly me . . . Later after posting this, i corrected my code. Thankzz